# Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully

Tags: python, pip, sentencepiece

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS D:\Translator> pip install sentencepiece
Collecting sentencepiece
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.99.tar.gz (2.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:15 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      -- VERSION: 0.1.99
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (project):
        Generator

          NMake Makefiles

        does not support platform specification, but platform

          x64

        was specified.


      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dpmwkzpa\sentencepiece_9e719dbab29d416994c7337531af3dca\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
          subprocess.check_call([
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'sentencepiece', '-A', 'x64', '-B', 'build', '-DSPM_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=build\\root']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
PS D:\Translator>
```

Comment: still same error

Comment: its working on my linux but not on my windows 11

Comment: Sounds like a question for the maintainer. Did you install cmake?

Comment: i have edited the issue, and posted the error which was occurred after installing cmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem with installing this package as can be seen on https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/591.

One way to fix this is to build and install the Python wrapper from source, try the following commands to build and install wheel package:

```
% git clone https://github.com/google/sentencepiece.git 
% cd sentencepiece
% mkdir build
% cd build
% cmake .. -DSPM_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./root
% make install
% cd ../python
% python setup.py bdist_wheel
% pip install dist/sentencepiece*.whl
```

If this doesn't work, you can try to [manually download the file for your platform](https://pypi.org/project/sentencepiece/#files). Be sure to choose the right file for your platform.

If none of these works, you may have to consider downgrading your python version to 3.10.

Comment: it worked when i downgraded my python to 3.10, because 3.12 dosent support sentecepiece